# Angular JS: Use different instances of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can we use two different instances of scope objects

For example :

```
$scope.seriesdata = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      ];
$scope.currentseries =  $scope.seriesdata;
```

Now if I update $scope.currentseries , $scope.series got automatically updated.

For Example :

```
$scope.currentseriesdata.splice(index,1);
```

This updates both $scope.currentseriesdata and $scope.seriesdata

Before writing this : I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814163/angularjs-sharing-scope-between-multiple-instances-of-same-directive)

I dont need to work in factory .

I just need to know how to have different instances within controller

Comment: '$scope.currentseries = angular.copy($scope.seriesdata);'  Making a second variable equal to an array just adds a reference, it does not make a copy.

Comment: Use 'angular.copy();'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the contents before operating on them:

```
$scope.currentseries = angular.copy($scope.seriesdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're assigning to `currentseries` reference to the array that is already referenced by `seriesdata`. This means you have two variables that point to one array.

You want to use `slice`

```
$scope.currentseries =  $scope.seriesdata.slice();
```